# linkbutton not firing the onclick handler and does not do a post back for the page

Tags: asplinkbutton

I have a user control and have a link button in it with onclick property but whenever i click this linkbutton nothing happened no postback for the page or firing the handler

I have added the **causevalidation** to **false** and add the **validationgroup** as well with no success
like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Approve" OnClick="Approve_Click" CauseValidation="false" ValidationGroup="approve"/>
```

any help Please i have been Searching about this issue 2 days with no success

Comment: Post your Code behind code too

Comment: my link button is in a user control for sharpoint web part and this is the code behind   protected void Approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string strID = "3";
                int RequestID = Convert.ToInt32(strID);

SPList lstRequests = currentWeb.Lists[lstGUID];
                SPListItem item = lstRequests.GetItemById(RequestID)
                item["ApproveStatus"] = "Approved";
                item.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbl.Text = ex;}
        }